# pdf is getting downloaded but failing to open in asp.net

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a piece of code which exports the Datatable to pdf. When I try to download the pdf, it downloads successfully but it get will not open.  I am using the iTextSharp library.  Here is my code:

```
var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);

var output = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer=  PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

document.Open();
iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);


Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

document.Add(p);


if (dt != null)
{
    //Craete instance of the pdf table and set the number of column in that table  
    PdfPTable PdfTable = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);

    PdfPCell PdfPCell = null;
    for (int rows = 0; rows < dt.Rows.Count; rows++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < dt.Columns.Count; column++)
        {
            PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dt.Rows[rows][column].ToString())));
            PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);
         }
     }


     document.Add(PdfTable);

     document.Close();

 }

 HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", reportname + "_Report_" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy_MMM_dd") + ".pdf"));
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(document);
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
 HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Can anybody please tell me what the problem is?

Comment: *HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(document);* - you have to write the contents of the memory stream 'output', not 'document'.

Comment: I wrote HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());And it worked..Thanks mkl

Comment: Ok, I'll make my comment an actual answer then.

Comment: Its ok..I  have one more doubt.Is there any way of adjusting the column widths of pdf table in the above code..

Comment: Please make that a stackoverflow question in its own right. I'm very sure it is possible but I use iText differently and, therefore, don't know the table layouting options well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP writes an iTextSharp `Document` instance to the HTTP response:

```
var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);

var output = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer=  PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

document.Open();

...

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(document);
```

This is wrong, that `Document` instance only is an object to forward material to which is to be arranged and drawn to the PDF. The actual PDF is output to the `MemoryStream` instance for which the `PdfWriter` is instantiated. Thus, this stream's content has to be returned.

In reaction to a comment to that effect, the OP fixed the problem using

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());
```

instead.